# What is the best practice for referencing JSON Schema for your state representations in REST?

Tags: json, rest, jsonschema

Let's say I have a REST end point that allows customers to `POST` a new `Article`. Its URL is http://api.example.com/articles. I also have an end point that they can `GET` a previously posted `Article`. Its URL is http://api.example.com/articles/{articleId}

The state representation for an article is like so.

```
{
    "title": "Some title",
    "body": "Article body"
}
```

So a raw `POST` request:-

```
POST http://api.example.com/articles HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/vnd.example.com.article+json
Host: api.example.com
Content-Length: 76

{
    "title": "Some title",
    "body": "Article body"
}
```

A raw `GET` request:-

```
GET http://api.example.com/articles/dfgh HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/vnd.example.com.article+json
Host: api.example.com
```

Now I have taken the time to provide a [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) schema to describe my article state representation. Hosted at http://spec.api.example.com/article.json

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "body": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "title",
        "body"
    ]
}
```

What is the best practise for making this documentation available to the customer for both `GET` and `POST` requests of this type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to document how to make a request is to use some hypermedia format to express it.  My personal preference is JSON Hyper-Schema and since you are already using JSON Schema, it's a natural fit.

A link to create an article would look like this.

```
{
  "rel": "create",
  "href": "/articles",
  "method": "post",
  "schema": { "$ref": "http://spec.api.example.com/article.json" }
}
```

So, the next step is to determine how to expose this link description object (LDO).  The answer to that depends on the flow of your API, but here are a couple common options.

**The API's Entry Point**

`GET http://api.example.com/`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Link: <http://spec.api.example.com/index.json>; rel=describedby

...
```

`GET http://spec.api.example.com/index.json`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "create",
      "href": "/articles",
      "method": "post",
      "schema": { "$ref": "http://spec.api.example.com/article.json" }
    }
  ]
}
```

**The article listing resource**

`GET http://api.example.com/articles`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Link: <http://spec.api.example.com/articles.json>; rel=describedby

[
  {
    "title": "Some title",
    "body": "Article body"
  },
  {
    "title": "Another title",
    "body": "Article body"
  }
]
```

`GET http://spec.api.example.com/articles.json`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{
  "type": "array",
  "items": { "$ref": "http://spec.api.example.com/article.json" },
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "create",
      "href": "/articles",
      "method": "post",
      "schema": { "$ref": "http://spec.api.example.com/article.json" }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An other notation for REST APIs is [RAML](http://raml.org/). It uses [YAML](http://yaml.org/) for describing your resources, and request/response bodies are defined using JSON Schema. There are tools which are able to generate documentation from a RAML description, but the use of this abstract definition of your API is not limited to documentation (other tools support fake server generation, etc)